# Transfer data from Oracle to Posgresql

Tags: postgresql, oracle

I have a system "A" that runs on Oracle and a system "B" that runs on Postgresql.
I have to transfer data from the Oracle application to the Postgresql application and I have no idea how to do that, could you help me?

Comment: There is a whole universe of ETL tools on the market.  Have you looked into any of them?  Are you using one of them already?  This is either a request for a recommendation on a tool, which is off topic, or is missing a ton of context (what tool you're using, whether you want real-time, near real-time, or scheduled pushes, what you've tried, what isn't working, etc.) which would be necessary to make it answerable.

Comment: Hello Justin
First of all, thank you very much for your reply.
I'm not using any yet. Could you recommend any (free)?
To be clearer, the University I work at uses a program developed in JAVA + Oracle and will switch to a program written in Python+Django + Posgresql.

Comment: Tool recommendations are off topic.  You can search "open source ETL tools" to see what tools exist and read reviews.  But evaluating tools is generally more involved.

Comment: If the Postgres server is on the same network as the Oracle server, you could use a foreign data wrapper in Postgres to access the Oracle tables from within Postgres

Comment: Or, conversely to @a_horse_with_no_name, you could use the Oracle Transparent Gateway for ODBC (free) to access the Postgres from the Oracle.